# Crystal Reports page footer not printing at the bottom of the page

Tags: crystal-reports

**Scenario** - We are developing a report using crystal reports. The report has to be printed on pre-printed template. The report is designed as follows - (*the colors used are just for helping identifying the problem when report is printed on paper*). We are using Visual Studio version 2010 with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010

[image: CrystalReportDesign]

**Problem** - When I am exporting the report to .pdf, or viewing it on screen the report looks perfectly alright, but when I print the report on paper, the page footer is not printing at the bottom of the page, it is printing about one and a half inches above the bottom of the page.

**Fix attempts -**

1. In CR designer page setup, the size of the page is given same as that of the pre-printed template (12 inches height)
2. Used page footer as it automatically prints at the bottom of the page
3. Also tried using "GroupFooter" and set the option "Print at the bottom of the page" to true
4. Page size set correctly in the printer preferences
5. Anticipating problem with the printer, used another printer, but for no help.
6. Extensive googling for the solution :)

Any help on fixing this up would be really invaluable. Thanks

Comment: Remove the tick on dissociate formatting page Size and printer Paper size

Comment: that used to happened to me in my previous job and the solution was the printer config in the pc, make sure that you have selected German standard fan-fold as sheet size to print 8 1/2 by 12

Comment: @cojimarmiami I 've tried this also, but for mo success :(. Thanks

Comment: what about if you adjust margins as 0.16 for right, left, top and bottom?

Comment: I think the problem are your margins, adjust them to 0.16 and them reorganize your fields in the report.

Comment: @vcs Doing this also didn't worked. Thanks.

Comment: @cojimarmiami; Actually the margins are set according to the pre-printed format. And it is good with all the sections. It is just the page footer that is causing problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the custom size paper that was causing the issue.

To reduce the gap, just decrease the top margin and shift the fields of page header and report header accordingly.